# Question preview tooltip is right justified

Tags: bug, status-declined, tooltips, localization

The preview for question in SO is right justified on my browser (My locale is Hebrew) as in this image:

[image: tooltip preview]

Is it possible to fix that?

Comment: I believe it's part of the default browser behavior, doubt it can be changed by code unless they switch to custom tooltip.

Comment: It's a title attribute, so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265449/can-we-center-align-text-in-title-tag and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011142/how-to-change-the-style-of-title-attribute-inside-the-anchor-tag - seems CSS3 might help

Answer (score 1):

This really is an issue with your browser defaults - it needs to be fixed on that side.  Without giving it *full* CSS3 styling (which would change tooltip looks for many users from *their* browser defaults), we can't accommodate this.

You could either:

- Change your browser locale
- Or use a browser extension on your side, e.g. Stylish in the case of [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en) or [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/)

Comment: I don't care *that* much, but saying "change your locale" for a minor inconvenience in a specific website is not a satisfying answer. Probably it's too minor so it really isn't worth the maintance headache, but it's a bug anyway. *In the website*.

Comment: @Elazar to be fair, don't you find that *all* web sites show their tooltips using right-to-left? Why then is the problem StackExchange's?

Comment: @Elazar a bug would be something *in our site*, your "bug" applies to every site with a multi-line tooltip...that's really not *our* issue.  It's totally on your side and a direct result of your locale settings...I hate to just leave it at that, but that's really where the problem in this case lies.  The browser extension is still a viable option if you want to change the behavior though.

Comment: @AaronBertrand it's pretty hard to find a website with multiline tooltip, so I really don't know. Give me an example.

Comment: @Elazar I've added a comment to a blog post. [Scroll to the bottom](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals), hover over "hover here" and let us know if you see something similar. If you do, I doubt you will get very far trying to get every web site to cater to your locale choice.

Comment: @NickCraver you say my browser is buggy. Could be. Could very well be.  But it is the same browser most of SO's right-to-left traffic is coming from, so the problem is *also* on my side. It does not make it a bug in the site. In my opinion.

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes, it is similar. I won't try it on any site - only those I care about and have certain expectation from.

Comment: @Elazar I think you've missed my point - it would be very cumbersome to ask any, never mind all, such English-language sites to build custom workarounds to a rendering problem on your specific locale. To be honest, I didn't even know there was a tooltip where you've found it - is such a thing really even important enough to talk about, especially since you have a workaround? Maybe it would be better for everyone if they just killed the tooltip.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have a problem, I know in this site it is probable I will get an answer, so I ask. I am not trying to change that decision now, I only think it is wrong. I like the idea of a tooltip showing me the question, but it won't happen. Too bad.